# How i can update object in array

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to know how i can update object in array.

I asked this question before,
and I got the hint at the moment but i can't still figure it out how to update x and y  ,
so here is my piece code :

```js
const [data, setdata] = useState([
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
  ]);
  
  
  const x= [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  const y =[ 1,2,3,4,6,7];
const updateX = () => {
  setdata((data) => data.map((d, i) => ({ ...d, x: newData[i] })));
  setdata((data) => data.map((d, i) => ({ ...d, y: newData[i] })))
};


/////result ///


    { x: 3, y: 2 },
    { x: 4, y: 2 },
    { x: 5, y: 2 },




/// what i want ///


    { x: 3, y: 1 },
    { x: 4, y: 2 },
    { x: 5, y: 3 },
    { x: 6, y: 4 },
    { x: 7, y: 5 },
    { x: 8, y: 6 },
    { x: 9, y: 7 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you are initializing the data object with those values.
The result you want, you can't get it by iterating the data object that you have initialized with 3 values.

Assuming that the arrays have these values and an equal length, you can try this:

```
const [data, setdata] = useState([
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 },
    { x: 1, y: 2 }
  ]);

  const x = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  const y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

  const newData = x.reduce((acc, xVal, index) => {
    const obj = { x: xVal, y: y[index] };
    acc.push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, []);

  setdata(newData)
```